# Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) Central Plugin for Apache Cordovaの使い方

Tags: javascript, ios, monaca, cordova, bluetooth

BLE CordovaPlugin(https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central/blob/master/README.md)
を使ってMonacaでiPhoneアプリを開発しようとしています。
実行環境: iPhone5s(iOS7)
プラグインを設定してjavascriptで以下コードを実行すると
javascript:

```
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady()
    {
        console.log("PhoneGap is ready");
    }
    $(function()
    {
            log("bbbb");
            scan();
            log("aaaa");
    })

    function log(str)
    {
        $("#log").append(str + "<br />");
        $("#log").scrollTop($("#log")[0].scrollHeight);
    }

    function scan()
    {
        log(">> scan");
        window.ble.scan([], 5, function(device)
        {
            log(JSON.stringify(device));
        }, function(reason)
        {
            log("ERROR: " + reason);
        });
        log("<< scan");
    }
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="log"></div>
</body>
```

実行結果が、

```
bbbb
>> scan
```

と表示されるだけでした。

期待している結果は、

```
bbbb
>> scan
[Device情報]
<< scan
aaaa
```

です。

iPhoneのコンソールログは、以下のようになります。

```
Apr  5 15:09:43 WWTF MonacaApp[957] <Notice>: DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie file: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3A33816B-D3DC-4EC2-8866-DEA6F2221654/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies
Apr  5 15:09:43 WWTF MonacaApp[957] <Warning>: Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
Apr  5 15:09:43 WWTF MonacaApp[957] <Warning>: Unlimited access to network resources
Apr  5 15:09:43 WWTF MonacaApp[957] <Warning>: [CDVTimer][monaca] 0.181019ms
Apr  5 15:09:43 WWTF MonacaApp[957] <Warning>: [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 33.852994ms
Apr  5 15:09:43 WWTF MonacaApp[957] <Warning>: [CDVTimer][statusbar] 11.131048ms
Apr  5 15:09:43 WWTF MonacaApp[957] <Warning>: Cordova BLE Central Plugin
Apr  5 15:09:43 WWTF MonacaApp[957] <Warning>: (c)2014-2015 Don Coleman
Apr  5 15:09:43 WWTF MonacaApp[957] <Warning>: [CDVTimer][ble] 1.643002ms
Apr  5 15:09:43 WWTF MonacaApp[957] <Warning>: [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 49.099982ms
Apr  5 15:09:43 WWTF MonacaApp[957] <Warning>: Status of CoreBluetooth central manager changed 5 State powered up and ready (CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn)
Apr  5 15:09:43 WWTF MonacaApp[957] <Warning>: Resetting plugins due to page load.
Apr  5 15:09:44 WWTF MonacaApp[957] <Warning>: Finished load of: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/5B3DD2D2-53DA-4040-B246-9E70DC9501A7/MonacaApp.app/www/index.html
```

iPhoneアプリのLightBlue等では正常にスキャンができて、デバイス情報が取得できているのは確認できています。

何が間違っているのかどなたかご教授して頂けないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。

以下のような原因がありました。

- PhoneGap初期化完了後に実行されるようにする必要がある。
- onDevicereadyの中でボタンリスナーを登録する必要がある。
- jQueryの$(function(){})では、PhoneGapの初期化が終わっていない場合がある。
- Monacaのプレビュー機能では、devicereadyが呼ばれない。

以下のコードで実行できるようになりました。

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            // are we running in native app or in a browser?
            window.isphone = false;
            if (document.URL.indexOf("http://") === -1 && document.URL.indexOf("https://") === -1)
            {
                window.isphone = true;
            }
            if (window.isphone)
            {
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            }
            else
            {
                onDeviceReady();
            }
        });

        function onDeviceReady()
        {
            $('#scan').on('click', function()
            {
                scan();
            });
        }

        function log(str)
        {
            $("#log").append(str + "<br />");
            $("#log").scrollTop($("#log")[0].scrollHeight);
        }

        function scan()
        {
            log(">> scan");
            ble.scan([], 5, function(device)
            {
                log("DEVICE: " + JSON.stringify(device));
            }, function(reason)
            {
                log("ERROR: " + reason);
            });
            log("<< scan");
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="scan" type="button">Scan</button>
    <div id="log"></div>
</body>
```